# Different graphical representation of same data with pyplot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, time-series

I have some datasets that I want to visualize. For example, let's see this Dataframe, Active addresses:

```
active_addresses["Active Addresses/t"] = pd.to_datetime(active_addresses["Active Addresses/t"])
active_addresses.sort_values(by='Active Addresses/t')
```

[image: dataframe]
If I simply use this command `active_addresses["Active Addresses/v"].plot()` then the plot is correct:
[image]
However, I want to use something different in order to modify labels, colors and so on. In particular, if I use this code:

```
plt.plot(active_addresses["Active Addresses/t"], active_addresses["Active Addresses/v"])
plt.gca().set(xlabel="Year", ylabel="Value") 
plt.show()
```

the result is this:
[image]
Please, note that this second picture shows something strange: it seems that lines are crossed or something similar. I do not know why.

Comment: make sure the dates are ordered

Comment: Note the `sort_values(by='Active Addresses/t')` where `Active Addresses/t` is a timestamp

Comment: Had missed that, but `sort_values` is not in place, you haven't assigned the output ;)

Comment: Yes, you are right! I solved